# Dynamic Category template paths

Tags: categories, localization

I've got a site with several locales and want to reuse a set of categories across locales but want to target a locale specific template from within each.

Is it possible to set a locale-specific path within the category group settings, eg

```
{{ craft.locale }}/_video
```

Cheers,

Cole

Comment: This is probably one for your routes.php. Depending on how you would want to structure your URLs. Another quick way around could be to use a shared template to include the correct template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this isn't possible. But what you can do instead is either:

- Route them to a shared template using the category settings and use `include` programatically:

  ```
  {% include 'myCatTemplate--' ~ craft.locale %}
  ```
- Disable "Categories in this group have their own URLs" in the category settings and add your own [dynamic routes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes).

Comment: Thanks - not really looked into dynamic routes before. Seems like a good opportunity to investigate further!